# Restricted WFS Layers in GeoServer for use in ArcGIS Online

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-online, wfs

I'm interested in adding a layer that is 'hidden' in GeoServer (i.e., not known publicly through the GetCapabilities document) to a public-facing ArcGIS Online map.

Online help (e.g., [this](https://geosolutionsgroup.com/news/gs-secured-with-agol/) document) have advised that this is possible through:

1. Creating a user group.
2. Creating a role and associating the user group to the role.
3. Configuring how the layers will be advertised. It might happen that the GetCapabilities is opened to anyone and that you may want to advertise or not the layer. This is done in the Data Security/Catalog mode configuration.

I have followed these steps by creating User Group 'restricted', role 'restricted' and adding the layer in question to this role with Catalog Mode "Hide". This hides the layer from the GetCapabilities document, though when attempting to add it to ArcGIS Online I have yet to find a WFS URL from our GeoServer which successfully loads the restricted layer in AGOL.

Has anyone solved this dilema before and if so how did you configure the settings in GeoServer to do so?

Comment: Does the WFS service provide features through a GetFeature request in a browser?

Comment: If AGOL is like several GIS desktop client applications, you may find that it requires the layer/featureType to be listed in the GetCapabilities response and allow it to do a DescribeFeatureType operation so it can work out what parameters it can apply to a request.  You can still use GeoServer controls to restrict access to the data though.    Setting up services with hidden layers/featureTypes is normally only an option when you are directly coding the requests into your own bespoke application.